# SerialPort Reads symbol instead of String

Tags: string, vb.net, arduino, serial-port, byte

I am connecting arduino to a Vb .Net program using a USB to serial Cable.

My arduino outputs a string "1" to its TX0 pin.

But whenever I am trying to read it to my Program, I cant have the string output.

I tried using ReadExisting(), Read() and ReadBytes()

When I try Using ReadLine() in goes Timeout.

```
    Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
    Dim Incoming As String
    Dim IncomingByte As Byte
    Dim byteArray() As Byte = {0, 0, 0}

    Try
        SerialPort1.Read(byteArray, 0, 3)

        Incoming = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)
        ' Incoming = ConvertByteToAsciiHex(IncomingByte)
        If Incoming Is Nothing Then
            Return "nothing" & vbCrLf
        Else
            Return Incoming + Environment.NewLine

        End If
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        Return "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    End Try

End Function
```

the output of this is "gy="

Here is my arduino code:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
 {
     Serial.println("1");
     delay(100);
 }
```

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your Arduino code also. But the code above seems like it should output three characters and it is returning three (gy=), so what's the problem?

Comment: I've already added the code of arduino

Comment: Arduino sends characters as ASCII and you are trying to read them as UTF8. Try to change encoding to ASCII and see if it helps. And check if you receive anything in some terminal program like Arduino serial monitor or putty

Comment: Even though I change it to ASCII the output is still the same. I my arduino monitor it is normal